# How to select only future days counting from today's date?

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I need a function that would only show future dates.

The problem goes like this "Select the patients who have booked advanced dates from today."

The selection code I have right now is this:

```
select Patients_code
     , max(Date) 
  from Patients
     , GPS 
 group 
    by Patients_code 
having max(Date) > '2016-05-11';
```

GPS is the booked times, where Date is.
Also, there are bookings that are still in 2016 but after a month and the answer I get are only 2017 dates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Is the `Patients` and `GPS` have any relationship column, like `PatientId` ?

Comment: Yes. The `Patients_code` is `PatientId`. `Patients` is the table. ALSO `GPS.PK` would be the `Patients_code` in the `GPS` booked table. And the booked date is also in `GPS.Date`. Hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: Well, problem 1 I see right away is you're using `MAX(Date)`.  `MAX()` is an aggregate and will make it so that only the max value of that column will show in your result for each row.  You'll want to put it instead in the `WHERE` and get rid of the `HAVING` like `SELECT * FROM Patients WHERE Date > NOW()` but I could be way off, update your question with some example tables and data like @Strawberry suggests and we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in PHP you might want to build your SQL like so:

```
    <?php
    //ADD AN END DATE TO SPECIFY A RANGE BETWEEN TODAY & THE ENDING DATE    
    $endDateRange   = "2016-09-30";

    $sql =<<<SQL
    SELECT Patients_code, max(Date) 
    FROM Patients, GPS 
    WHERE (Date >= CURDATE() && Date =< '{$endDateRange}')
    GROUP BY Patients_code 
SQL;
```

Assuming your End Date is **2016-09-30**, this might boil down to:

```
    SELECT Patients_code, max(Date) 
    FROM Patients, GPS 
    WHERE (Date >= CURDATE() && Date =< '2016-09-30')
    GROUP BY Patients_code
```

Here is another Flavour...all of which are saying the same thing:

```
<?php
    //DECLARE A VARIABLE TO HOLD NR. OF DAYS INTO THE FUTURE:
    $daysFromNow   = "120";     //120 DAYS INTO THE FUTURE - APPROX. 4 MONTHS FROM NOW.
    $sql =<<<SQL
    SELECT Patients_code, max(Date)
    FROM Patients, GPS
    WHERE ( DATEDIFF(MAX(Date), CURRENT_DATE()) < {$daysFromNow})
    GROUP BY Patients_code
SQL;
```

Which also otherwise implies (assuming the Range is **120 Days into the Future**):

```
    SELECT Patients_code, max(Date)
    FROM Patients, GPS
    WHERE ( DATEDIFF(MAX(Date), CURRENT_DATE()) < 120)
    GROUP BY Patients_code
```

@kamal pal pointed out that you might not need the **having** Clause. Now, I don't pretend to know what you want to do but I think he may have have made a good point... although it all depends on you and what your intention really is. This part is yours to decide... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thank you all for your help this was very helpful!

What I had to do:

```
select GPS.PK, Date, Name, Lastname from Patients, GPS where Date>NOW() and PatientsID=GPS.PK and PatientsID=645;
```